# calling a web service in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have two textbox and a button, and a web service. I want to enter a number(cu_personal_number) in textbox1 and when I click the button, it connects to web service and search in it and return the name belong to that cu_personal_number in the textbox2.
my code did not return value. When I enter a code in textbox1 and enter the button, there is not any value appear in the textbox2.

```
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        localhost.Personel lp1 = new localhost.Personel();
        DataSet ds1 = lp1.daryafte_view_Personel_Information_with_parameter_cu_personal_number("cu_personal_number");
        this.GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
        bool found = false;
        foreach (System.Data.DataTable tabale in ds1.Tables)
        {
            foreach (DataRow dr in tabale.Rows)
            {
                found = true;
                txtName.Text = dr["tp_firstabbr_name"].ToString().Trim();
            }
        }
```

Comment: *"my code did not work"* is ***not*** a technical description of a problem

Comment: Please share details about you web service code and how response is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check what are the Values your "tabale" return, if there is single row as result then there is no need of Foreach Loop.
if Table has single row the use below to get value.

txtName.value = `tabale.rows[0]["tp_firstabbr_name"].tostring()`